# RSAPrivateKey returns RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, openssl

Im trying to get the RSA keys to OpenSSLRSAPublicKey and OPENSSLRSAPrivateKey format on Android.

The keys look like this (generated automatically, do not work):

> Private key string:
>   MIICWwIBAAKBgHfvJ1jB80KZTaEYClqbM0znYlos0qTenOF+BSjC4DT31rCwLgMJ
>   5/c7jSUuzH34OypP8Z7sGMz4UIXzXRGUKXA0TFXvq3aKNMGa74SCB3AGJmjb4yvT
>   rXpTytfeuJsodJzBmwsCkgfkAYZBH06OJAxNPpqoUMUZHOg61hTHwm9nAgMBAAEC
>   gYBC8L3yYVaITo6won1s8wEgJGmV0TzE/udrSG5SwOppRgeTWNJlqcrKCHgQT92d
>   VcaYKETBIh/5j4NKMHo6zIqPpH7GxzNuG3Ua+pmi6VOcdFs7O071q6zAt9aLb/Dd
>   rs7gJb5/H2/LuJBbKInKb+c0IUMEQ9AFoAc70q+um4eJmQJBAOxugXf7LFlCrfun
>   TuR5eYVjLBM9pmVRMEYJcp9CH7qtTAKhdHAKgnZ7Sw3gTxtBi+msnm3zXwtzO/cY
>   Xjh+m7UCQQCB3E8xvJWICLpX/11saDUOZsoaC53A7SunptkbAyJ49yE8SVg3O92i
>   kqRBlFho1JL84vDZe10GXwxj6O1XwigrAkAAzfN01A73ksmCxLP5BQzLzmWU/y20
>   xIz0gA26yv/Oo85RZ/k8dFyzSIId3viF8DgoqGS1nRFiuZanpZaUfKHNAkAuQwDH
>   dCpE+u7/eE6c1wbHqaCn5Kl/WD5sDEldkSFPvKJPasWNb7tGNj1jy2gveEMg6evp
>   XkRGh8fPM+SRle5fAkEAmaQeOnryugbQBVOAj006jEQaidYsF8FNnKSAyxPQlbSC
>   Nee4pL/hKkjqtm5zKgEp8f0dHRhz5vb94EdLnl1DJA==
>
> Public key string:
>   MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgHfvJ1jB80KZTaEYClqbM0znYlos
>   0qTenOF+BSjC4DT31rCwLgMJ5/c7jSUuzH34OypP8Z7sGMz4UIXzXRGUKXA0TFXv
>   q3aKNMGa74SCB3AGJmjb4yvTrXpTytfeuJsodJzBmwsCkgfkAYZBH06OJAxNPpqo
>   UMUZHOg61hTHwm9nAgMBAAE=

This is my code:

```
public static RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromString(String key) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    String privateKeyPEM = key;
    privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
    privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    byte[] encoded = Base64.decode(privateKeyPEM, Base64.DEFAULT);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    ///////// Line below is (RSA.java:37)
    RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
    return privKey;
}
public static RSAPublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    String publicKeyPEM = key;
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    byte[] encoded = Base64.decode(publicKeyPEM, Base64.DEFAULT);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
    return pubKey;
}
```

The interesting thing is that the pubKey returns this:

```
OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=9920c2.....,publicExponent=10001}
```

But the privKey gives me this exception:

```
W/System.err: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0890ba:ASN.1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:WRONG_TAG
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPrivateKey(OpenSSLKey.java:283)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:64)
W/System.err:     at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:187)
W/System.err:     at com.vladmarton.educomiit.RSA$override.getPrivateKeyFromString(RSA.java:37)
```

I browsed the stackoverflow for a long time but I did not find any working solution. I need to have them in the exact format as the pubKey, but cant get the private key to work.

Comment: *"But the privKey gives me this exception..."* - Try `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.

Comment: tried, always the same

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Actually, I didnt. The problem was only with the private key. We fixed the private key (explanation below). I think it was a problem with the key formatting. For some reason, it shouldnt have started with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----, but just -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----, or so. Check your keys and try to play around with them. Anyway, if it helps anyone, the public key was accepted by Cipher using this configuration:
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
 c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publickey); .....i guess it depends on key format

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static PublicKey buildPublicKey() {
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(publicKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        Logger.e(Logger.TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
 private static PrivateKey buildPrivateKey() {
    String key= privateKey.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\r+", "").replaceAll("\\n+", "");
    try {
        byte[] keyByteArray = Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyByteArray);
        return kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.e(Logger.TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```